# Get ClassName without referencing self

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I want to initialize a UIViewController subclass with a default nib name. The only way I can think is to get the current class name. But to do it, I need to reference self, and it is not possible before calling super.initWithNib.

```
    init(managedObject: NSManagedObject){
        let className = PSOClassNameFor(self) /// ERROR -> Cannot reference self

        self.managedObject = managedObject
        super.init(nibName:className, bundle: nil)
    }
```

I don't know the actual name for the class, since this is an abstract class with multiple subclasses.

Any other way to load a default nibName?

These are the two files in play:

[image]

When I try to initialize with a  nil nibName it load a black screen.

```
 init(){
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

When I specify the nib name it works as expected:

```
    init(){
    super.init(nibName: "EntityCardViewController", bundle: nil)
}
```

Comment: If the nib name is the same as the class name, you can just pass nil for the nib name.

Comment: Yes it is, but setting the nib to nil is not working for me. Updated the question

Comment: Why would a C++ answer apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but this just worked fine in Xcode 6.4/Swift 1.2:

```
import CoreData
class MySubVC: UITableViewController {
    init(managedObject: NSManagedObject){
        let className = self.dynamicType.description()
        println(className) // Project_Name.MySubVC; not so bad; easily parsed
        super.init(nibName: className, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init!(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. The difference is that I'm calling a function PSOClassName(self). If I reference self.dynamicType the compiler won't complain. I made the function so I can remove the first part of the dynamicType description. Thanks

Comment: Right, but to pass self, all of self must be available, but here self.dynamicType is obviously special, as a compiler entity, and guaranteed to be initialized before all class properties. But I'm sure you knew this or just figured it out. Interestingly Xcode doesn't like to autocomplete `dynamicType`.

Comment: I did not know that I could reference self.dynamicType before calling the super initializer. Just figured it out with your answer. I did noticed that it does not autocompletes. It looks hardcoded somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3:

```
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: nil)
    }
```

Comment: You may want to add a little more description.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. I have a `UIViewController` which should never be initialised itself. Several `VC`s subclass from this, which have their own nib. Now I only have to implement this once in the superclass. 
Works for Swift 5.x too!